# What would be a nice (almost perfect) django settings and apache conf configuration?

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, settings

I know it is a bit a newbie question,
and that by reading a lot of docs about django and apache
I might find my perfect configuration..

But I am still a bit confused also because if you google you
find a lot about devel but little about running systems.

So I'd like to collect here a bit of additional info.

I decided that it is better to have a local server for
development then to use the:

```
python ./manage.py runserver
```

[it works fine for small projects and apps but as soon as you start
to get close to real it gets complicated]

What I know is:
 - Static files will be served by the apache.

What I guess is:
   I guess that django will address these files to the apache
   which will be "ignored"(?) by django.
   These are the settings: MEDIA_ROOT, MEDIA_URL
   I am not sure about: STATIC_ROOT, STATIC_URL
   [ok, assuming I do not mess up the url.py..]

Now the title question:
What would be a good apache (and unix permissions) configuraton?
How can I distinguish between MEDIA and STATIC?

Maybe I do miss something.

**PS:**
At present I have these aliases in apache:

```
Alias /admin-media /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media
Alias /things_media /home/udev/prj/DjangoSite/www/things_media
```

Comment: Modern Django does not use admin-media, all static files are served from `STATIC_ROOT`. Actually, you don't even need to use Apache for development. Django can [serve all necessary files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development) itself.